# How does $e^{0.196t}\frac{dv}{dt}+0.196\,e^{0.196t}v=9.8e^{0.196t}$ become $e^{0.196t}\frac{dv}{dt}=9.8\,e^{0.196t}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why does this:

$$e^{0.196t}\frac{dv}{dt}+0.196\,e^{0.196t}\,v=9.8\,e^{0.196t}$$

Simplify to this:

$$e^{0.196t}\,\frac{dv}{dt}=9.8\,e^{0.196t}$$

just can't find it no matter what I do

Original problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that in the original problem it is not $dv/dt$ but $d(e^{0.196t} v)/dt$. In the original problem the second line follows from the first using the product rule for derivatives (backwards).

Comment: Got it, thanks Gary. I had written it down wrong. Time for a break haha!  Appreciate the help!